# QSystemTrayIcon popup menus are not displaying if the application is busy

Tags: qt

I using QSystemTrayIcon class to display TrayIconMenu and the popup menu will display while clicks on the TrayIconMenu.

If the application is busy processing other tasks, then click on the TrayIcon, the popup menus are not showing, but menu border is visible  for a while. The same code is works on Mac.

The following way I am trying to display the menu:

```
    QMenu *myMenu();
    QSystemTrayIcon myTrayIcon;
    myTrayIcon.mytMenu()->show();
```

Comment: There's a number of ways you can overcome this. This article might be useful to you: [Keeping the GUI Responsive](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html)

Comment: Thanks dschulz,I will try to understand this.

Comment: @dschulz Link gone! Can you explain what it contained?

Comment: @ThePeacefulCoder corrected the broken link. If it still fails, please reload the page and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is with some extensive computational block or a big and slow loop. If you know where is this bottleneck, you can let the event loop to process queued events simply inserting

```
QApplication::processEvents();
```

at some point inside the computational loop.

Also, try to split the big and expensive tasks into little and fast tasks, you can let the event loop to process events in between.

Comment: thanks Felix, I will try to implemet processevents as temproary fix.

Comment: sometimes this is the only disposable solution, not a temporary one!